# JWindow task bar icon not shown

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jwindow

I have created a java program that does not use a `JFrame`, instead it is using a `JWindow`.  This is exactly what i needed, an application without the windows border/title bar.

The problem is it does not show in the task bar at the bottom of the screen when its running.

Can anyone figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [undecorated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-) `JFrame` instead.